# Is there a homomorphism of some group of 6 elements into some group of 12 elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a homomorphism of some group of 6 elements into some group of 12 elements?

I have researched and have found an answer. Which is true. I've been solving some problems Fraleigh book and I found this exercise, the answer gives me the following example: Define $f : \mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ by $f(n)=2n$, but for $f(0) \rightarrow 0$, $f(1) \rightarrow 2$, $f(2) \rightarrow 4$, $f(3) \rightarrow 6$, $f(4) \rightarrow 8$, $f(5) \rightarrow 10$, then I only see 6 elements $\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$ and I found other example $g : \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}$ when $g(a)=(a,0)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, then $\{(0,0), (1,0)\}$. But honestly I do not understand how they got these results, could you please explain? My specific question is how can I find an example or counterexample?

What is the difference between the following questions?

- Is there a homomorphism of some group of 6 elements into some group of 12 elements?
- The imagen of a group of 6 elements under a homomorphism may have 12 elements?

Thanks for your time... I will be reading you.

Comment: In the first example, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is a group of twelve elements, and $f$ is a homomorphism into that group.  The size of the image does not matter for the question asked in the title.

Comment: The image of a group of $6$ elements under any *function* may have at most $6$ elements, homomorphisms included.

Comment: In sounds like you are confusing "into" with "onto". The image of a finite set under *any* function, homomorphism or not, is always of lesser or equal cardinality to the domain set. So you can only have an image of at most $6$ elements, if you are coming from a group with $6$ elements. There is, of course, no *onto* homomorphism of a group with $6$ elements into a group with $12$ elements, since functions can only have one image per domain element, at best (some functions, like constant functions, send multiple domain elements to the same image).

Comment: Let's see if I understood. If we are talking about an injective homomorphism (into), then if $f:G \rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism and $H=ker f$  the there is a bijection between cosets of $H$ and elements of $fH$ applying first theorem of isomorphism $|fG|=|G|/|H|$ divides $G$. In particular if $|G|=6$ then we can't have $fH=4$ because there is no number that divides 6 and as a result 4... Am I ok? @DavidWheeler

Comment: How can I built a similar argument to surjective homomorphism (onto)?

Comment: Concerning the first question, what about the trivial homomorphism?